# Converting a bitmap image from JSON array to a hashmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I was trying to put a JSON array of object into a hashmap.The object contains images which is in base64 format.I converted the image to bit map and need to put the image in a List view using a hashmap.But i am getting a null pointer exception

```
#Main Activity#

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

         try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
             details = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Root);
                for(int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String branch = c.getString(TAG_Branch);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_Add);
                String uname = c.getString(TAG_User);
               String photo = c.getString(TAG_Photo);

               //decoding the base64 image to an png format

                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(photo.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
               image.setImageBitmap(
                     BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
                );


                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_Branch, branch);
               map.put(TAG_Add, address);
               map.put(TAG_User, uname);
              oslist.add(map);

              HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
              map.put(TAG_Photo,image);
              oslist.add(map);

              //String.valueOf(TAG_Photo
                //,R.id.imageView1
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_activity,
                        new String[] { TAG_Branch,TAG_Add, TAG_User }, new int[] {
                                R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        int pos=position;
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+pos).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting null because of the map

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(TAG_Photo,image);
```

the adapter won't find the needed tags in it so it will give null exception.

Comment: i added the tag for the map in the adapter, still its having  null pointer exception.since the hashmap is initialized as as <String ,Object) does it accept other tags as they all are strings

Comment: @Elizabeth you can create a custom adapter and handle the object or save your effort and create another arraylist to keep bitmaps

Answer (score 0):

If `photo`'s value is base64 string content, I think you don't need `photo.getBytes()`

```
String photo = jsonObject.getString(TAG_Photo);
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```